# Как вставить переменную в поле ajax data, передать ее значения

Tags: ajax, запрос

Есть переменная:

```
STR="f_trassa": ["op_1_5","op_1_2"],"f_dom": [].
```

И есть  Ajax где пункт data: `{STR}`

На сервер приходит:

```
[str] => \"f_trassa\": [\"op_1_5\",\"op_1_2\"],\"f_dom\": []
```

А надо, чтобы сервер получал переменные:

- `f_trassa` - массив 2-х значений
- `f_dom` - пока пустую.

Много что перепробовал и переискал.

Answer (score 0):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow!

```
...
data: { 
  f_trassa: ["op_1_5","op_1_2"], 
  f_dom: [] 
},
...
```

или

```
var dataToSend = { 
  f_trassa: ["op_1_5","op_1_2"], 
  f_dom: [] 
};

...
data: dataToSend,
...
```

или

```
var dataToSend = {};
...
dataToSend.f_trassa = ["op_1_5","op_1_2"];
...
dataToSend.f_dom = [];

...
data: dataToSend,
...
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но,  Данные собираются постепенно в переменную. Необходимо отправить именно переменную.

Comment: @Андрей так тоже можно - смотрите третий вариант.